# Why this RewriteEngine rule is not working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to understand how to do an URL rewrite using .htaccess file.

The easier-to-digest information that I've found so far is [here](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php), and I'm trying to adapt it to my own needs, but unsuccessfully so far.

I have this url:

```
http://www.example.com/contenido.php?id=19
```

and I want at the moment to transform it into:

```
http://www.example.com/contenido/19
```

I've tried an .htaccess file with:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contenido/([0-9]+) http://www.example.com/contenido.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

When I try the clean url I get a "server not found" error.

Any insight will be very appreciated.

Please note that `RewriteEngine` is ON in my Apache server.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to test if the pages exist, as you rewrite all the contents of the directory.

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect contenido.php?id=nnn to contenido/nnn
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+contenido\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /contenido/%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally rewrite contenido/nnn to contenido.php?id=nnn
RewriteRule ^contenido/(\d+/?)?$ contenido.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little help from [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049), I've found a solution.

Just in case it helps someone I'll post it here:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^contenido/(\d+)*$ ./contenido.php?id=$1
```